# Convert string to date time in specified format

Tags: python, datetime

I have a string `"Monday, May 18, 2015"`. I want to convert it into datetime fromat of python keeping the format same. I mean exact replica of the string but the type changed to datetime. How can I do that?

Comment: A [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) does not *have* a format, it can be *formated using a format*. What you ask for makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

date_object = datetime.strptime('MAY 18 2015  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
```

Link to the Python documentation for strptime :https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

and a link for the strftime format mask : https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: Now we have a `datetime.datetime` instance. Fince. The second part of an answer would be to format this instance as a string.

Comment: And it would be nice if the format applies to OP's example

Comment: @Yalami Please don't put code into a comment, [edit] your answer instead.

Comment: this is a direct copy paste of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/466376/2141635

Answer (score 0):

To convert string to date object:

```
from datetime import datetime

your_date_object = datetime.strptime("Monday, May 18, 2015", '%A, %b %d, %Y')
```

To change back date object to string:

```
your_date_object.strftime('%A, %b %d, %Y')
```

For more derivative behaviour:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score -1):

Use the classmethod of `datetime.strptime(date_string, format)`. This will return a datetime corresponding to **date_string**, parsed according to **format**.

Comment: How is your answer different from the existing two answers? It is a bad copy.